# Coroutines Exception handling

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to understand the internals of coroutines and found the following while dealing with exception handling:

Below is the suspend function That I am using:

```
private suspend fun getMoreUsers(): ArrayList<User> {
        Timber.e("getMoreUsers task started : ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        delay(1000)
        Timber.e("getMoreUsers task finished")
        throw IllegalStateException("exception thrown manually")
        val list = arrayListOf<User>()
        list.add(User("Deepu", 13))
        return list
    }
```

Now If I use the below code then it does not crash:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
            try {
                val result = lifecycleScope.async { getMoreUsers() }
                val user = result.await()
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                Timber.d("$exception handled !")
            }
        }
```

But if I use this code, it crashes:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
            try {
                val result = async { getMoreUsers() }
                val user = result.await()
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                Timber.d("$exception handled !")
            }
        }
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: exception thrown manually handled !
 4246-4246   E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                Process: com.vicky7230.learncoroutines, PID: 4246
                java.lang.IllegalStateException: exception thrown manually
                    at com.vicky7230.learncoroutines.MainActivity.getMoreUsers(MainActivity.kt:68)
                    at com.vicky7230.learncoroutines.MainActivity.access$getMoreUsers(MainActivity.kt:12)
                    at com.vicky7230.learncoroutines.MainActivity$getMoreUsers$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:14)
                    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:235)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:168)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:474)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:508)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:497)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeUndispatched(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:595)
                    at kotlinx.coroutines.android.HandlerContext$scheduleResumeAfterDelay$$inlined$Runnable$1.run(Runnable.kt:19)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
                    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@e983b76, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
```

I am not able to understand why it crashes in the second case but not in the first case.

Comment: When you say “crashed”, you don’t mean the app crashed, do you? Just that the coroutine printed a full stack trace?

Comment: When I say crashed, I mean the app crashed

Answer (score 2):

To understand this, we first need to know when coroutines treat exceptions as unhandled:

> Coroutine builders come in two flavors: propagating exceptions automatically (launch) or exposing them to users (async and produce). When these builders are used to create a root coroutine, that is not a child of another coroutine, the former builders treat exceptions as uncaught exceptions, similar to Java's Thread.uncaughtExceptionHandler, while the latter are relying on the user to consume the final exception, for example via await or receive (produce and receive are covered in Channels section).

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html

That means the error happens only if we fail the coroutine started in `lifecycleScope.launch`, because that would be a root coroutine. Also, exceptions are automatically propagated from children to parents.

In your first example you start a root coroutine using `lifecycleScope.launch`, then inside it you start another root coroutine using `lifecycleScope.async`. The second coroutine fails, but as it is a root coroutine started using `async`, it isn't treated as an unhandled exception. Then the exception is thrown in the first coroutine in the `await` line, however, you catch this exception, so it doesn't fail the first coroutine.

In your second example you also start a root coroutine using `lifecycleScope.launch`, but inside it you start a child coroutine using `async`. This time the second coroutine is not a root coroutine, it is a child of the first coroutine. If the second coroutine fails, the exception is automatically propagated to its parent. Even if we catch the exception from the `await`, the first coroutine is still considered failed, because one of its children failed. And because the first coroutine is a root coroutine started with `launch`, if it fails, this is treated as an unhandled exception.

Comment: And might be worth mentioning, when we do have a child coroutine whose failure we do not want to propagate up, we can wrap it in `supervisorScope`

Answer (score -2):

Thanks Buddy, It is a great question. When first time I had seen it, I just though it was the issue, which is related to other parts of code. But when I code it by myself, I also got the same error. I studied about it And try to figure out the reason. So I will try to explain what I had find out about the reason of the crash->
**Basic kotlin Coroutine Knowledge**
As we know, we use async-await to handle asynchronous functions in kotlin. So when we execute a piece of code in async block ,if everything goes fine... It will pass the value to the await. But if, within the async function error occurs it won't crash the async function then and there, instead it will store it as a Job object and then pass it to await. and then we can handle exception in await using try-catch block. As you had done in your First piece of code. For reference I would share my first piece of code..

**Difference between first code and second code**
The major difference between first and second code is that in the first it is launched in the proper coroutine scope and in second is not.

**Why CoroutineScope is important?**
When using async block without any scope, errors in the coroutine might not be send correctly to the main code.With coroutineScope, any exception thrown within the scope is send to the main code, allowing for proper error handling.

**Why only lifecycleScope**
You may use other scopes also. lifecycleScope is a specific CoroutineScope tied to the lifecycle of an Android component. Using lifecycleScope.async ensures that coroutines are aware of the Android component's lifecycle. If the component is destroyed, the associated coroutines are automatically canceled, preventing potential memory leaks and crashes.

**Why try-catch doesn't handle exception in second case?**

**The problem is not with the catching of the error but the problem is with properly sending the error to the main program : **

If an exception is thrown within the getMoreUsers() function before the await() block is called, the exception might not be caught by the try-catch block. This is because the coroutine is not tied to the Android component's lifecycle, and the cancellation is not handled.

**Summary**
It makes a proper robust error handling to use scope with any coroutine function even if you use it inside try-catch block. Because if any error occurs inside the async function and the function will be handled properly by the lifeCycle scope.

I hope you may understand this edited answer.
Thanks

Comment: ```The major difference between first and second code is the place where async block is implemented. In the first code it is implemented outside the try block and in second code it is implemented inside the try block. The issue is here only.``` But in both cases asycn block is wrapped up in try-catch. I am a little confused.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question. I had edited my answer . I hope it may help you.

Comment: Almost every sentence in this answer is wrong. It’s not necessarily more proper to avoid child coroutines and instead launch sibling coroutines. In fact, usually you should prefer child coroutines for structured error handling and encapsulation. In the second case, the exception *is* caught. It just gets thrown again at the end of the `launch` block. The coroutine *is* still tied to the scope’s lifecycle because it is a child coroutine of a coroutine in that scope.

Comment: @Prakhar_Pathak Are you coping the responses from chat gpt?